# Accessing a Mac machine on a network using hostname

Tags: macos, svn, networking

I have three Mac machines in a wi-fi network. I have set up SVN server on one of these machines (say A). Now, I am trying to access the SVN server on A from the other machines(say B & C).
I am able to access the same using the IP address of A. On A, I modified the /etc/hosts to include an entry for the current IP address and a host name. On A, I am able to access the SVN server with the hostname now. However, from B & C I can not access the SVN server on A using the hostname.
Is there a way I can achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated.
UPDATE: The IP of A keeps changing. I am hoping to find a way in which I can use the same hostname on B & C (without any changes on B&C), by changing the entry in hosts file in A.
The checkout / working copy taken from the SVN server is rendered useless now when the IP changes.

Comment: Are you using the full name, which has .local prepended to the end? If you look at the sharing pane in System Preferences, it tells you how to address that machine by name from another machine on the same network.

Comment: Yes, I can access the machine by using the computer's name. However, this name cannot be used to acces the SVN server set up on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
e.g. 192.168.1.10 svnServerA
192.168.1.11 clientB
192.168.1.12 clientC
```

*You also have to put an entry of ip & hostname of 'svnServerA' in /etc/hosts*  in 'clientB' and 'clientC' machines. The reason is because you don't have DNS service running for your local network.

For running DNS server locally in your network, this 'superuser' question answer might be helpful https://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network for you.

Comment: oh..I did figure this out but was wondering there could be a way around it. :( The issue is I am working on a wi-fi network, and the IP keeps changing. I was hoping that with the hostname, I will be able to use the same hostname on B & C to access the SVN server, by changing the entry in hosts file in A only.

Comment: Then setup local static IP for your machines than DHCP. This may help. http://superuser.com/questions/311418/how-to-set-static-ip-in-laptop-to-be-used-with-wireless-network

Comment: This might help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5145/maintaining-etc-hosts-for-hosts-on-dhcp

Comment: Thanks for your help and guidance Ankit. I have requested the network administrator here for a static IP for the system A. The links were helpful too.

Comment: Glad to hear. My pleasure Sahitya. All the best!